# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:a foreign key while placing new order from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders

I am getting below error while placing new order from admin panel

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 
Cannot add or update a child row: 
a foreign key constraint fails (sales_flat_order_item, CONSTRAINT sales_flat_order_item_ibfk_1 
FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
REFERENCES sales_flat_order (entity_id))
```

> This error is generated randomly not all time

I know magento insert in table `sales_flat_order_item` after order is inserted.(FROM Mage_Sales_Model_Order :: _afterSave() method).

what would be cause for this ?

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517891/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-chi

Comment: @Hitesh  i know that.  i am asking related to default magento flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to deadlock. due to deadlock it rollback first transaction of order insertion and continues to insert in other reference tables so it throw Integrity constraint error